# Voltage Current and Voltage Charge Relationship for a Capacitor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

1. The voltage-current relationship for a capacitor is described by Eq. \eqref{1}:
   \begin{equation}
   \mathrm{v}\left(\, t\, \right) =
   \frac{1}{C}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{i}\left(\, \tau\, \right)\,\mathrm{d}\tau
   \label{1}\tag{1}
   \end{equation}
2. The voltage-charge relationship for a capacitor is described by Eq. \eqref{2}:
   \begin{equation}
   \mathrm{v}\left(\, t\, \right) =
   \frac{1}{C}\,\mathrm{q}\left(\, t\, \right)
   \label{2}\tag{2}
   \end{equation}
3. How can I prove that
   $\,\mathrm{q}\left(\, t\, \right) =
   \int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{i}\left(\, \tau\, \right)\,\mathrm{d}\tau$ ?.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you want is
$$
q(t)= \int_0^t i(\tau) d\tau
$$
This comes from integrating both sides of the definition 
$$
\frac{dq}{dt}= i(t)
$$

Comment: Before performing the integration of both sides do I need to multiply both sides by $dt$ to get $dq = i(t)dt$?

Comment: @SpaceBeer Both "yes" and "no" are possible here. You can do it without multiplying by $dt$, just integrating both sides as functions of $t$ and applying Newton-Leibnitz formula $\int \limits_{a}^{b} F'(x) dx = F(b) - F(a)$ to the $\frac{dq}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ to answer your question. From equation $(1)$, you have
$$
v(t) = \frac{1}C\int_0^1 i(\tau)\,d\tau\label{a}\tag{1}.
$$

From your equation $(2)$, you have
$$
v(t) = \frac{1}{C}q(t)\label{b}\tag{2}.
$$

Therefore, multiply equation $(2)$ by the capacitance $C$ on each side to obtain
$$
q(t) = Cv(t)\label{c}\tag{3}.
$$
Substitute the value of $v(t)$ from equation $(1)$ into $(3)$, and you're done:
$$
q(t) = C\left(\frac{1}C\int_0^1 i(\tau)\,d\tau\right) = \int_0^1 i(\tau)\,d\tau.
$$